# Ruby automatically populate Lineitems to an order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, associative-array

Fairly new to Ruby and I have looked around but can't really find anything on this...

I have a typical has_many-through relationship between Orders, Lineitems, and Items.  I want to be able to automatically create a lineitem list containing each item in the Items table for an Order when it is saved to the database.

I am thinking a loop that will cycle through each item in the Items table and save a new Lineitem record for each would do the trick, but not quite sure how to implement it.

I know an after_save callback could be used to initialize a method once an Order is created.

Here is my thought process for a method in the Orders model...

```
items.each do |x|
  Lineitem.new(order_id=>@order.id,item_id=>x.id)
  Lineitem.save!
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is not only Ruby question..tag it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this:

> I want to be able to automatically create a lineitem list **containing each item in the Items table** for an Order when it is saved to the database.

You can use callbacks to handle this. You don't have to do loops:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :add_lineitems

private
  def add_lineitems
    # This will associate all items in the items table with the new order.
    # It'll automatically add records to the lineitems table.
    self.item_ids = Item.pluck(:id)
  end
end
```

Comment: wow, so simple.  It works.  I have methods doing calculations at the lineitem level.  All methods run fine.
Thanks a ton!